# How to search a specific byte string in process memory in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to understand how `find` in `gdb` works. From the first looks, its behavior is... weird if not plain wrong:

```
(gdb) p *(char*)0x464408@50
$5 = "untrusted comment: minisign public key 99312DBDB49"

(gdb) find 0x464000, 0x465000, "minisign public key"
Pattern not found.
```

Which calls for a WTF... the string is there at the address `0x464408`, yet `find` doesn't find it?

Let's try hexdumping the string maybe? Perhaps the NUL character interferes?

```
(gdb) p/x *(unsigned char*)0x464408@10
$8 = {0x75, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20}

(gdb) find 0x464000, 0x465000, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20
Pattern not found.
```

Nope.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `/b` for bytes:

```
(gdb) find /b 0x464000, 0x465000, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20
0x464408
1 pattern found.
```

The `help find` says this, perhaps a bit buried away from a hurried eye:

> `(gdb) help find
> Search memory for a sequence of bytes.
> Usage:
> find [/size-char] [/max-count] start-address, end-address, expr1 [, expr2 ...]
> find [/size-char] [/max-count] start-address, +length, expr1 [, expr2 ...]
> size-char is one of b,h,w,g for 8,16,32,64 bit values respectively,
> and if not specified the size is taken from the type of the expression
> in the current language.
> Note that this means for example that in the case of C-like languages
> a search for an untyped 0x42 will search for "(int) 0x42"
> which is typically four bytes.
> The address of the last match is stored as the value of "$_".
> Convenience variable "$numfound" is set to the number of matches.`

---

Still, `find /b <start>, <end>, "literal string"` w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ will do something else than what one might foolishly expect.

So you better convert your string to hex bytes beforehand; `gdb` can (much helpfully) do that for you:

```
(gdb) p/x "literal string"
$5 = {0x6c, 0x69, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x0}
```